# Запускаю django-admin.py makemessages --all

Tags: django, django-admin

Запускаю команду из проекта в консоли - **django-admin.py makemessages --all**
Выдает ошибку - CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.

gettext установлен на windows (gettext0.21-iconv1.16-static-64.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Просто перезагрузил комп)